# add field in logstash with a stripped information from another field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, opensearch, grok

Is there a valid function in logstash "add field" to strip a hostname to a part of it.

i have variations of hostnames from a haproxy.log like this

- cccrz1-qa01.exserver.int
- cccrz2-qa01.exserver.int
- preaccccrz1-qa01.exserver.int
- preaccccrz2-qa01.exserver.int
- conaccccrz1-qa01.exserver.int
- conaccccrz2-qa01.exserver.int

and want to add the information "ccc" from it to an additional field.

- preac/conac prefixes

and

- rz1/rz2-qa/dev/live.ex.server.int

are mandatory parts of the hostnames.
At the end i dont want to mess with the haproxy grok pattern